# Ubuntu 12.04 black-screen and totally freezes switch user

Tags: switch-user, lockup

How to troubleshoot this issue is my question. I don't know how to go about this.

I set up an account for my wife to use the computer for her homework.  I log in automatically.  She logs in and does her homework.  I switch users.  The kernel locks up.  CTRL+ALT+F1-12 do nothing.  This happens somewhat randomly but always after I've selected the user and before.

There is somewhat of a random graphical glitch on the screen suggesting it may be due to a video change of some type.  I am running dual displays.

How do I find out what the problems is?